# Youtube embed: Hide title/subscribe/comments when logged in to youtube/google

Tags: youtube

I'm using showinfo=0 to hide the title, etc. in an embedded youtube video.  This works fine for users not logged in to youtube/google, but logged in users see title, subscribe, comments, video owner's image, "watch later", etc.  See screenshot here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NCrZ.jpg

I've never noticed this before and wondering if it's a new "feature" from youtube/google.  Would love to find a way to hide this info for all users viewing the embedded video, regardless of if they're logged in to youtube/google or not.

Comment: What have you tried so far in this direction?

Answer (score 1):

As per Google states on its YouTube Player API Docs on 23rd of August 2018:

> Note: This is a deprecation announcement for the showinfo parameter.
>   In addition, the behavior for the rel parameter is changing. Titles,
>   channel information, and related videos are an important part of
>   YouTube’s core user experience, and these changes help to make the
>   YouTube viewing experience consistent across different platforms.

You can read full document [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018)

Seems like Google does not want to disable/hide video related information like

- Relative Videos (if the rel parameter is set to 0, related videos will
  come from the same channel as the video that was just played.)
- Video Info (showinfo parameter is deprecated and will be ignored after
  September 25, 2018.).

So the bottom line is, the rel parameter has now changed and you can no longer disable this. Instead of this you can use other Video players Like

- [Plyr](https://plyr.io/)
- [Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/)
- HTML Video Player

Hope This Helps!.